# Como realizar una consulta y que me liste las filas de la consulta con php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema con mi codigo estoy realizando un codigo de php para hacer una select a una base de datos y que me liste las filas de los resultados de la query pero me da error y no consigo verlo , me da error en el foreach y no entiendo el porque, os agradeceria que me ayudarais .

```
<?php
 print_r($_REQUEST);
 if (isset($_REQUEST['abogados'])) {
     $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
     $nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
     $colegiado=$_REQUEST['colegiado'];
 }
 const MYSQL_HOST = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=luidiu';
const MYSQL_USER = 'alejo';
const MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'patata';

// FUNCIÓN DE CONEXIÓN CON LA BASE DE DATOS MYSQL
function conectaDB()
{
    try {
        $tmp = new PDO(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
        $tmp->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
        $tmp->exec("set names utf8mb4");


        return $tmp;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        print "    <p class=\"aviso\">Error: No puede conectarse con la base de datos.</p>\n";
        print "\n";
        print "    <p class=\"aviso\">Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>\n";

        exit();
    }
}
$db = conectaDB();


 $consulta="SELECT $id,$nombre,$colegiado from abogados";
 $result=$db->query($consulta);
 foreach ($result as $valor){
     print "    <tr>";
     print "   <td> $valor[id]</td>\n";
     print "   <td> $valor[nombre]</td>\n";
     print "   <td> $valor[colegiado]</td>\n";
     print "    </tr>";

 }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué error te da?

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR;

El método `query()` de PDO no te devuelve los datos en sí mismos, sino un recurso o puntero hacia los datos. Debes por tanto recorrer ese puntero, aplicándole el método adecuado para obtener los datos.

Por el tipo de lectura que se ve dentro del bucle aplicaría el método [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) pidiéndole un array asociativo:

```
$consulta="SELECT $id,$nombre,$colegiado from abogados";
 $result=$db->query($consulta);
 while ($valor = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     print "    <tr>";
     print "   <td> $valor[id]</td>\n";
     print "   <td> $valor[nombre]</td>\n";
     print "   <td> $valor[colegiado]</td>\n";
     print "    </tr>";
 }
```

Aquí el `while` iría moviendo el puntero fila por fila, sacando en cada paso del bucle los datos por cada fila/columna.

---

Recomiendo siempre que leas la documentación sobre los métodos y elementos que estés usando. En el caso concreto de `query()` que es el que nos ocupa, el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php) dice que:

> `PDO::query` — Ejecuta una sentencia SQL, devolviendo un conjunto de
> resultados como un objeto `PDOStatement`

¿Qué signifca esto? **Que `query()` no devuelve los datos en sí mismos**, sino un objeto `PDOStatement`. Pues bien, en la definición de la clase PDO, [un objeto`PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php):

> Representa una sentencia preparada y, después de la ejecución de la
> instrucción, un conjunto de resultados asociados.

Cuando se ejecuta la consulta, tu objeto `$result` es **un conjunto de resultados**. O sea que un `PDOStatement` ¡tampoco son los datos en sí mismos!. Un `PDOStatement` es algo así como un recurso o un puntero con los datos.

¡Vaya lío! ¿Y cómo se leen los datos entonces? Pues si lees la documentación (enlace anterior), verás que `PDOStatement` tiene **varios métodos** para leer los datos, son todos los que empiezan por `fetch`. Cada uno de esos métodos tiene usos específicos y según qué contexto convendría usar uno u otro.

Para el caso que nos ocupa, se indicó más arriba un tipo de lectura que consistía en usar `fetch` con el parámetro `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. En la documentación verás que hay varios tipos de estilos para organizar los resultados que vas a leer.

En resumen, leer la documentación y analizar los ejemplos te ayudará a entender por qué algunas veces el código no funciona.

---

### Advertencia sobre la seguridad

En el contexto de tu código, usar variables para nombres de columnas no te da ninguna ventaja. Más bien expone tu código a un grave riesgo de *Inyección SQL*.

Generalmente las tablas/columnas son entidades bien definidas en una aplicación, por lo que no tiene sentido usar variables para ellas. De hecho, el dato que usas para leer dentro del bucle define cada columna por su nombre, por lo que es mucho más seguro escribir tu consulta de este modo:

```
 $consulta="SELECT id,nombre,colegiado FROM abogados";
```

El problema de las variables aquí es que un usuario mal intencionado podría manipularlas para escribir consultas dañinas, no sólo para la base de datos, sino para todo el servidor. Sí, en ciertos contextos puedes incluso escribir en el sistema de archivos por medio de instrucciones SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique tu consulta desde una prueba en la BD, y realmente funciona como lo tienes, considero que revises tus valores uno por uno, quizá uno de ellos es el problema o verifica si los nombres de las columnas coinciden, me hice casi el mismo ejemplo a excepción de la conexión y este fue el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que utilice es similar, por eso digo que revises los valores de la BD:

```
function connect(){

try {
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;
    dbname=test;charset=utf8","root","");

return $link;

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $err= $e->getMessage();
    return "error please verify the conection $err";
  }
}

$db=connect();

$sql='SELECT id, nombre, colegiado FROM abogados';
$result = $db->query($sql);
foreach ($result as $v) {

print "    <tr>";
print "   <td> $v[id]</td>\n";
print "   <td> $v[nombre]</td>\n";
print "   <td> $v[colegiado]</td>\n";

}
```

Inicialmente lo hice de esta manera (la conexión es la misma):
Pude comprobar que puedes usar `prepare()` o `query()` y obtendras el mismo resultado sin problema incluso si usas o no `fetchAll`, aunque de igual forma considero mejorar la estructura de las consultas para que sean más robustas en seguridad.

```
$sql='SELECT id, nombre, colegiado FROM abogados';

$stmt = connect()->query($sql);

//$stmt = connect()->prepare($sql); Puedes usar prepare o query

$resultado = $stmt;
//print_r($resultado);
foreach ($resultado as $v) {

echo $v['id'].' '.$v['nombre'].' '.$v['colegiado'];

echo '<br>';
}
```